# FsCheck Generators by Selecting From Pools of Possibilities

Tags: f#, fscheck

Is there a way to generate a string in FsCheck by selecting just one item from each of a list of strings and then concatenating the result?

I'm just completely stuck and can't seem to figure it out. I've looked at the [docs](https://fsharp.github.io/FsCheck/) and in the [github](https://github.com/fsharp/FsCheck) repo for something similar. And I've done most of my reading on FsCheck from [FSharpForFunAndProfit](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/property-based-testing/).

This is something like what I would be thinking of:

```
let rand = System.Random()
let randInt max = rand.Next(0, max)

let selectLetter (string: string) = 
    let whichLettersIndex = String.length string |> randInt
    string.Substring(whichLettersIndex, 1)

let generateOddlySpelledWord listOfStrings = 
    List.map selectLetter listOfStrings
    |> String.concat ""

let usingGenerateOddlySpelledWord =
    generateOddlySpelledWord ["zZ"; "oO0Ò"; "eEê"]
```

That should generate something like "Z0ê" or "zÒE".

Comment: Write the function you want that generates a `string seq` then apply `Gen.elements`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
open FsCheck

let createGenerators (l : string seq) =
    l |> Seq.map Gen.elements |> Seq.toList

type OddlySpelledWords =
    static member String() =
        ["zZ"; "oO0Ò"; "eEê"]
        |> createGenerators
        |> Gen.sequence
        |> Gen.map (List.map string >> String.concat "")
        |> Arb.fromGen
```

Ad-hoc test:

```
open FsCheck.Xunit

[<Property(Arbitrary = [| typeof<OddlySpelledWords> |])>]
let test (s : string) =
    printfn "%s" s
```

Output (truncated):

```
  z0ê
  ZÒe
  ZOe
  zoê
  ZÒe
  zoê
  Z0e
  zoê
  z0ê
  ZOe
  zÒê
  z0E
  zoe
```

**Explanation**

The `createGenerators` function has the type `seq string -> Gen<char> list`, and it creates a `Gen` from each string using `Gen.elements`, because a string is also a `char seq`; `Gen.elements` creates a `Gen` that will pick one of these `char` values from each string.

Then it uses `Gen.sequence` to convert the `Gen<char> list` into a `Gen <char list>`, and then maps from there.

---

BTW, you can also inline `createGenerators`:

```
type OddlySpelledWords =
    static member String() =
        ["zZ"; "oO0Ò"; "eEê"]
        |> List.map Gen.elements
        |> Gen.sequence
        |> Gen.map (List.map string >> String.concat "")
        |> Arb.fromGen
```

Comment: +1 Great answer, and also well crafted (as shown from [its edits](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28798955/revisions))! – How about using `List.reduce (+)` instead of `String.concat ""`?

Comment: The problem with `List.reduce` is that it's fragile, so I tend to avoid it. Try this if you don't believe me: `List.empty<string> |> List.reduce (+)`.

Comment: +1 Indeed, out of curiosity, `List.empty<string> |> List.reduce (+)` throws an ArgumentException saying that the input list was empty.